# Inquiry about server with both Internet & External Connection

Tags: linux-networking

May I know if the following connection is erroneous?
[Existing Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S0at.png)

If the following topology allows single server nic to both internal & external connections?

[Broadband router to Dual Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3wgD.png)

Comment: You have labeled the two connections with "LAN1" and "LAN2", but they are both using the same local address space. If they really are separate LANs, they should have different addresses, or the broadband router in the "after" picture will have a hard time figuring out its interfaces. (Also, the "before" picture has a similar quirk: the MetroE and Broadband routers look like they are on the same network, so having the server "between" them seems to be a slight misconception.)

Comment: Hi Bass, thanks for your reply. For diagram 1 "Existing Topology", the linux server gi1 and gi2 IP cannot be on the same subnet, right?

Comment: For diagram 2 "Broadband router to dual network connections". I think about my ASUS broadband router have multiple LAN ports for PCs connections (all their gateways pointing to the broadband router LAN IP)  with one WAN port for broadband connection. It also allows static route added to the router. Is it possible both the linux server and the Cisco router are plugged to the LAN ports  (all their gateways pointing to the broadband router LAN IP) connect the broadband modem to the WAN port?